# javafx Why is there a flickering with this event handler?

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason there is a flickering effect that happens when I use the setOnMouseEntered/Exited

Any ideas? Shouldn't it wait for me to leave the button before it removes killThis.
Also, as a note, the button isn't under killThis, so that's not the issue.

```
button.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>
           () {
               public void handle(MouseEvent t) 
               {
                   killThis = cardDrawer.drawCard(button.getCardID());
                   layout.getChildren().add(killThis);
               }
            });

            //Exit hover over button
            button.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>
             () {
                 public void handle(MouseEvent t) 
                 {
                    layout.getChildren().remove(killThis);
                 }
             });
```

This is what was loaded in with the drawCard();

```
public StackPane drawCard(int I)
{
    StackPane cardViewer= new StackPane();

    CardList cards= new CardList();
    ImageView background = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getBackgroundID())));
    ImageView frame = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getFrameID())));
    ImageView nameFrame = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getNameID())));
    ImageView valueFrame = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getValueID())));
    Text textName = new Text(cards.getCardList()[I].getName());
    Text textMana = new Text(""+ cards.getCardList()[I].getManaCost());
    textName.setFont(Font.font("Verdana",FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    ImageView attackBoarder = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getAttackBoarderID())));
    ImageView healthBoarder = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(cards.getCardList()[I].getHealthBoarderID())));
    Text textHealth = new Text("" + cards.getCardList()[I].getActHealth());
    textHealth.setFill(Color.RED);
    Text textAttack = new Text("" + cards.getCardList()[I].getActAttack());

    textName.setTranslateY(-225);
    frame.setTranslateY(-50);
    nameFrame.setTranslateY(-225);
    valueFrame.setTranslateX(-175);
    valueFrame.setTranslateY(-200);
    textMana.setTranslateX(-175);
    textMana.setTranslateY(-200);
    healthBoarder.setTranslateX(185);
    healthBoarder.setTranslateY(125);
    attackBoarder.setTranslateX(-185);
    attackBoarder.setTranslateY(125);
    textHealth.setTranslateX(185);
    textHealth.setTranslateY(125);
    textAttack.setTranslateX(-185);
    textAttack.setTranslateY(125);

    cardViewer.getChildren().add(background);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(frame);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(nameFrame);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(textName);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(valueFrame);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(attackBoarder);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(healthBoarder);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(textHealth);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(textAttack);
    cardViewer.getChildren().add(textMana);

    return cardViewer;
}
```

**EDIT:** So I decided to move the killThis to the right border and the issue was resolved, but the node wasn't in the way of the button. Any thoughts?

Also sorry about the minimal, complete, and verifiable parts, theres just A LOT of code to put in and I thought it was a quick fix. :P

Comment: Typically this would happen if the new node appeared in a location where the mouse was over it. It could also happen if the appearance of the new node caused the button to move or change size, and there are probably other ways this could occur. It's basically impossible to know why this would be happening just from the event handlers. Create a [MCVE] that displays the same issue as the one in your application and [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: Your edit makes it neither complete, nor minimal. "Complete" means a complete executable application (it doesn't mean your complete project). "Minimal" means it has enough to reproduce the problem, but nothing superfluous.